# How to keep the relative position of the child BrowserWindow when parent Browser Window moves?

Tags: linux, windows, electron

I'm trying to "fix" the known issue present in Linux and Windows : https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/browser-window#platform-notices `On macOS the child windows will keep the relative position to parent window when parent window moves, while on Windows and Linux child windows will not move` .

This piece of code:

```js
SearchWindow.on("move", function (event) {
    let position = SearchWindow.getPosition()
    console.log("SearchWindow is moved to position ", position[0] + " , " + position [1])
    if (event) {
        child_window.setPosition(position[0], position[1]) // https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/browser-window#winsetpositionx-y-animate
    }
})
```

Catches some BrowserWindow movements, but not all of them .  Any ideas on how to permanently fix it?

Answer (score 0):

With :

```ts
clearTimeout()

let t: string | number | NodeJS.Timeout
    if (t) {
        clearInterval(t)
    }

    t = setInterval(() => {
        SearchWindow.on("move", function (event) {
            let position = SearchWindow.getPosition()
            //console.log("SearchWindow is moved to position ", position[0] + " , " + position [1])
            if (event) {
                child_window.setPosition(position[0], position[1]) // https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/browser-window#winsetpositionx-y-animate
            }
        })
    }, 10)
```

I increased the frequency of position resetting, and it seems that now the time lag is shorten. Not a perfect solution, but a kind of improvement